# Prove that a finite $p-$group $G$ with a unique subgroup $H$ of index $p$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following question: Prove that a finite $p-$group $G$ with a unique subgroup $H$ of index $p$ is cyclic.

Since the subgroup is characteristic it is normal. I showed that either the center of the group $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$ or $G=Z(G)H$ and the index $Z(G)/(Z(G)\cap H)$ is $p$. But I couldn't continue from this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is due to Alexander Gruber (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296986/abelian-p-group-with-unique-subgroup-of-index-p)): If $G$ is finite then every proper subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup, so every proper subgroup is contained in $H$, the unique subgroup of index $p$.  Therefore we have $\langle x \rangle = G$ for any $x\in G\setminus H$.

Comment: Why is any maximal subgroup of $G$ actually contained in $H$ ? Is there any simple argument for this (e.g. without Sylow theorems, as it is done in Marshall Hall's book, theorem 4.3.2) ?