# The maximal subfield of $\mathbb C$ not containing $\sqrt2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Related:

[Does a maximal subfield of $\mathbb C$ not containing $\sqrt{2}$ have index $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836973/does-a-maximal-subfield-of-mathbb-c-not-containing-sqrt2-have-index-2)

He said,

"...fixed field is an extension of $K$ which doesn't contain $\sqrt{2}$, and thus must be $K$ itself. Thus, **the Galois group is cyclic**..."

Why is that so?

Could you give a reason or hint?

Thank you!

Comment: There's not any "the" maximal subfield not containing $\sqrt 2$. Take for example $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2\pi)$. We can extend each of these to **a** maximal subfield not containing $\sqrt 2$ (by Zorn's lemma), but those maximal subfields cannot be the same.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for your comment. Can you give some advice about What I asked?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/143020/11619).

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to the group theoretic proposition that any 2-group with unique subgroup of index $2$ is cyclic. A proof is here:[Abelian $p$-group with unique subgroup of index $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296986/abelian-p-group-with-unique-subgroup-of-index-p)

To see the reduction let $L$ be any alg. ext. of $K$ and $E$ its normal closure.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $E/K$ then $G$ is a $2$-group since if the $2$-sylow subgroup has index, which must be odd, greater than $1$ then you get an odd extension of $K$. Further any extension contains $K(\sqrt{2})$ and so there is a unique subgroup of index $2$. It then follows that $G$ is cyclic and all intermediate fields are also Galois and cyclic.

Comment: Thnks a lot! What if we replace $\sqrt2$ by any irrational number which is in a algebraic closure of Rationals. Simialr Can work? I don't see...

Comment: If it has prime order then al least I think its clear.

Comment: I think it reduces to this case by an easy argument so... yes.